# What is the best data structure for this sensordata?

Tags: python, django, database, data-structures

I'm currently working on a project to store sensordata in a database using the Django framework. I'm receiving a data object that has 19 data fields, which can be interpreted differently depending on the type of measurement. For the sake of this question, I'm going to simplify the data fields to five fields. The received data looks like the following example:

```
{
  "data type": 1
  "values":[12, 18.4, 14, 15, 1]
}
```

The data values can be interpreted depending on the data type. So for example, the lookup table might look something like this:

---

*Data type 1*: Climate control

| field | description | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Room temperature | C |
| 2 | desired temperature | C |
| 3 | Cooler power percentage | % |
| 4 | Valve position | % |
| 5 | Power supply | kWh |

---

Each of these data types might have a different interpretation of the given data. The amount of different data types might change over time, so I need this to be a flexible solution.

### The question

How would I go about storing this data in the best way possible? Do I:

1. Store the raw values in the database, and define the context of the values in the model?
2. Add context in the database like so? [image: Example database]

I'm happy to hear your opinion!

Comment: probably what you want is to do a database normalization. I cant say.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by storing all the sensor data (19 fields) in a single timestamped model with any additional categorical values as foreign keys.

For the following reasons:

Firstly, I'm going to make a huge assumption here in that the reason you wan to collect the data is due to the source system has limited storage capacity, you want additional reporting capabilities or you only get a point in time feed.

If this is the case, you want to preserve the data as close to how you originally received it as possible. The source system might change, you may get additional data points or the scale changes which will inevitably break things, you should be able to fix these types of issues in one place.

If you're wanting to programmatically insert these values (REST API for example) it will also make things a lot simpler when inserting. This is an easy way to keep your inserts atomic, if the insert fails there is no commit made and you don't have to go cleaning up partial commits due to having to add data via multiple models.